# mxGraph insertEdge - Edge Color

Tags: javascript, node.js, mxgraph

We are writing a program to generate a graph using mxgraph

Newbie question please

When using insertEdge we want to indicate specific color or otherwise it will take the default style color,

What is the Style String that we need to add as the last parameter to insertEdge ?
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `strokeColor` element in the style of the edge as in the following example which overrides the default edge stroke color to use 'black' (and other style elements)

```js
const v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Pump', 20, 20, 60, 60,vertexStyle);
const v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Tank', 200, 150, 60, 60,vertexStyle);
const e1 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', v1, v2,
                    // edge style
                    'strokeWidth=3;endArrow=block;endSize=2;endFill=1;strokeColor=black;rounded=1;'
);
```

It is taken from the mxGraph animation example

- source: https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/v4.2.2/javascript/examples/animation.html#L40
- live example: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/animation.html